# Воспроизведение мр3 с интернета

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Могу ли я закинуть мр3 файлы на облако, и с помощью media player воспроизвести их? Как нужно указать обращение на ссылку?

Comment: в датасорс вставляете Uri Файла из ссылки, и все. Не понимаю вообще, почему вы не можете найти ответ на этот вопрос в гугле? Вам хватит 23 секунды для этого

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String url = "http://..."; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
//You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
        mp.start();
    }
});

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when MediaPlayer
        //  is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPD:**

```
int index = 0;

public void play(MediaPlayer player, String url) {
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

final ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add("...");
urls.add("...");
urls.add("...");

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
play(mediaPlayer, urls.get(index));

//You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
         mp.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          index++;
          if (index < urls.size()) {
              play(mediaPlayer, urls.get(index));
          }
    }
});
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when MediaPlayer
        //  is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Как быть если файлов много ?

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, задать OnCompletionListener, который срабатывает когда файл доиграет до конца, и вызвать reset(), setDataSource, и prepare() снова, но с другой ссылкой

Comment: не составить труда пример написать ? Ника не могу разобраться ((

Comment: я если честно не знаю что вы получаете от того что ответили на вопрос. Но я готов отправить вам небольшое вознаграждение. Я не первые сутки мучаюсь с этим. Новичек и не разбираюсь

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, обновил ответ